# Can I include cin within a switch statment

Tags: c++, switch-statement, cin

I am writing a program that will give the area of a shape and I have to create a menu for the user to pick a shape using switch. So my question is can I have cin with the switch case or do i have to format my code differently.

```
#include <cmath>
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <cassert>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    int shape, invalid;
    double area, radius, width, height;

    const double pi=3.14159;

    cout << "Shape Menu"<<endl<< "1. Circle"<<endl<<"2. Rectangle"<<endl<<"3. Triangle"<<endl
    <<"shape (1, 2, or 3)? ";
    cin >> shape;


        switch (shape){
            case 1: cout << "Radius? "<<;
            cin >> radius >> endl;break;    // this is were my error is when I compile 
            case 2: cout << "width? ";
            cin >> width >> endl;
            cout << "Height? ";
            cin >> height >> endl;break;
            case 3: cout<< "Base? ";
            cin >> base >> endl;
            cout << "Height? ";
            cin >> height >> endl;break;
            default: invalid = shape 
            cout<< shape << "is an invalid menu option, program terminated."<<endl;
            assert (invalid == T)
        }


        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Post a [MCVE] and state what problems you actually have verbatim please.

Answer (score 0):

`case 1: cout << "Radius? "<<;` you have a stray `<<` after `"Radius?"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can include `cin` after the cases of switch statements. The cases like `case 1:` are just labels. So the instructions after can be any instructions.

Your code just has many compilation errors: here is a possible replacement for your switch statement.

```
    switch (shape){
        case 1: cout << "Radius? ";
        cin >> radius;break;    // no more error here 
        case 2: cout << "\nwidth? ";
        cin >> width;
        cout << "\nHeight? ";
        cin >> height;break;
        case 3: cout<< "Base? ";
        cin >> base;
        cout << "\nHeight? ";
        cin >> height;break;
        default:
        invalid = shape;
        cout<< shape << "is an invalid menu option, program terminated."<<endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fullfil with an enum and switch:

```
#include <iostream>

enum SHAPES{CIRCLE = 1, SQUARE, RECTANGLE, TRIANGLE, CUBE};


int main()
{
    int choice;
    std::cout << "1: Circle  2: Square  3: Rectangle  4: Triangle  5: Cube" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " >> ";
    std::cin >> choice;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    switch(choice)
    {
        case CIRCLE:
        {
            //do something
        }
        break;
        case SQUARE:
        {
            //do something
        }
        break;
        case RECTANGLE:
        {
            //do something
        }
        break;
        case TRIANGLE:
        {
            //do something
        }
        break;
        case CUBE:
        {
            //do something
        }
        break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Bad Entry!" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use cin in switch statement. There is no such bound. you are getting errors because of many other syntactically wrong statements in your code. Check @Franck's answer as he has already corrected them. If you want to read more on Switch statement. These are some good references.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm

http://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/switch-case